# How do I know when a CATiledLayer has rendered all visible tiles?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation

I am working on an application where I render PDF content in a CATiledLayer.  I want to trigger one method after the rendering of the tiled layer is complete.

Is there any delegate method that will be called immediately after the rendering of all visible tiles is completed?  Is there any other way of knowing when this is finished?

Comment: just hitting randomly, cant drawLayer:inContext: be used in conjuction with some count mechanism? as the documentation suggests that it can be called in multiple background threads.. something like.. increment the counter when starting the method, and call its super, and decrement it when exiting. if this really stupid, will also like to know why? :)

Comment: @Joe Blow I am not doing it in back ground.

Comment: No ,i did some work around.Each time the draw layer is called i am firing a method which triggers a perform selector after some delay (i kept it to .3 sec and is working in my case),before triggering the selector i am canceling previously scheduled perform selector .Assuming that draw layer is called with in .3 sec of time for each tile,the last call to my call back method executes the perform selector.I know this is not good idea but i had no choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the number of tiles your drawing requires before it's drawn. In drawRect of the tilingview, each tile is drawn only ONCE. So put a counter in part of the draw rect that calls a new tile. When your counter reaches the total number, call your method.

Keep in mind that drawrect for tiling is done on a background thread.

Comment: Actually there is a bug in CATiledLayer that causes it to call drawRect for the same tile twice from different threads on dual core environments, which causes this approach to fail. In my tests of an image with 9 tiles, it calls drawRect anywhere between 10 and 16 times in iOS 8.1. Very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

This requires some creative thinking. I've had a similar problem where I've needed to abort the rendering of a tiled layer mid-cycle. The way I worked round it is somewhat complex, but seems to work reasonably well. It involves wrapping the draw calls to the tiled layer inside a `NSThread`. Threads have a `isFinished` bool that you can key-value observe to discover when a tiled layer has completed its render.

If you're not comfortable with threading on iOS this may be more trouble than its worth, but will give you the advantage of knowing when the rendering has finished, and also being able to cancel the thread operation (and thus the render) if required.

Comment: Hi, can you say a little more about how you did it? Canceling the catiledlayer drawing in the middle of a cycle would be really handy at times but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. In my case drawRect is called from at least 2 background threads. How did you wrap these calls in some "outer" thread?

Comment: I'd like to second @bor's request, even over a year after the first post. There's still no straightforward solution to it. Would you like to elaborate, @lxt?

Comment: @epologee I think a year was enough for me to understand what he meant... :). Prepare a function that will encompass all the drawing operations (basically just a content of drawRect) and call that function indirectly in drawRect by using NSThread. Set up k-v observation to be notified when the thread is finished. When all report-in finished - destroy the tiled layer. Is that what you did @lxt?